# NodeJS Express Inner Join Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express

I am using NodeJS with Express and I am trying to execute an inner join statement as follows:

```
    getAllGrades: function(callback) {
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM questions INNER JOIN questionanswers ON (questions.questionNo=questionanswers.questions_questionNo) WHERE questionanswers.users_userNo = 2 AND questionanswers.softdel = 0";
    con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        }
        else {
            callback(null, result);
        }


    });

},
```

This callback function has worked for my previous queries and works for normal select statements, however, this callback always returns null. I typed this exact statement on MySQL Workbench and got a result:

```
SELECT * FROM questions INNER JOIN questionanswers ON (questions.questionNo=questionanswers.questions_questionNo) WHERE questionanswers.users_userNo = 2 AND questionanswers.softdel = 0;
```

Why is this NodeJS query returning null when my SQL compiler doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Super silly, forgot to add my database name..`SELECT * FROM mydb.questions INNER JOIN questionanswers ON (questions.questionNo=questionanswers.questions_questionNo) WHERE questionanswers.users_userNo = 2 AND questionanswers.softdel = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

You won't have to add the db name if you configure it in your `msql.createConnection`

eg:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password : 'yourPasswordHere',
  database : 'mydb'
});
```